# I am submitting a sitemap.xml in google webmaster tools but not all urls are getting indexed

Tags: google-search-console

Here is my Sitemap.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <!-- Generated by Sitemaps.NET 1.1
  -->
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.friendisc.com</loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.friendisc.com/Login.aspx</loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.friendisc.com/Signup.aspx</loc>
  </url>  
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.friendisc.com/UpdateProfile.aspx</loc>
  </url>  
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.friendisc.com/Friends.aspx</loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.friendisc.com/Share.aspx</loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.friendisc.com/Groups.aspx</loc>
  </url>  
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.friendisc.com/Messages.aspx</loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.friendisc.com/Wall.aspx</loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.friendisc.com/ChatRoom.aspx</loc>
  </url>  
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.friendisc.com/BookReview.aspx</loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.friendisc.com/MovieReview.aspx</loc>
  </url>  
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.friendisc.com/Questions.aspx</loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.friendisc.com/AskQuestion.aspx</loc>
  </url>  
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.friendisc.com/ViewSong.aspx</loc>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

Comment: which one is missing?¿

Comment: MovieReview, BookReview and Groups